# how to get the other side of a polymorphic relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, polymorphic-associations

I have the following:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  # assets
  has_many :assets, :as => :assetable, :dependent => :destroy

class Asset < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :assetable, :polymorphic => true
```

And would like to be able to do:

```
a=Asset.find(5)
a.item  # no dice
```

How would I get the associated item starting with the asset?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to get the associated item, you need to use the relationship name that you setup in the Asset class. Since you have declared this relationship as `:assetable`, you need to refer to the item as "assetable".

Assuming you have your database setup correctly according to the [Rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations), you should be able to do the following:

```
a=Asset.find(5)
a.assetable
```

Answer (score 1):

When you create a polymorphic model (Asset in your case), the corresponding table has to have both an _id and a _type column to refer to the related polymorphic record. In your case, this asset record needs to have assetable_id and assetable_type (a string equal to "Item"). Then, when you call a.item, the model knows to look in the "Item" table for the record with id == assetable_id.